# Unable to get my :class to be dynamic using my data property in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a page that when you select a category then specific parts of the page will change color.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not getting my `:class` to grab my data property

This is my code

```
<template>
    <a href="#step-1" type="button :class="{`cat-${categoryNameClass}-color`: step_1_active}" class="btn btn-primary" @click=changeCatStep('step1')>Step 1</a>

    <a href="#step-2" type="button :class="{`cat-${categoryNameClass}-color`: step_2_active}" class="btn btn-primary" @click=changeCatStep('step2')>Step 2</a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: [],
        return {
            categoryNameClass: null,
            step_1_active: false,
            step_2_active: false,
            step_3_active: false,
            step_4_active: false,
        },
        computed: {
          
        },
        methods: {
            getCategories(){
                axios.get('/api/categories').then(response => {
                    this.categoryNameClass = response.data.catClass
                });
            },
            changeCatStep(step){
                if(step === 'step1')
                {
                    step_1_active: true,
                    step_2_active: false,
                    step_3_active: false,
                    step_4_active: false,
                }

                if(step === 'step2')
                {
                    step_1_active: false,
                    step_2_active: true,
                    step_3_active: false,
                    step_4_active: false,
                }
            }
        },
        mounted(){
          this.getCategories();
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what `this.categoryNameClass` returns ? It's string or an array ?

Comment: @CreativeLearner - it returns a string

Comment: try :class="step_1_active ? \`cat-${categoryNameClass}-color\` : ''"

Comment: @Romalex - that worked. Now I just need to figure out how to get it to color as soon as I click on it and not when I click somewhere else on the page

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few observations :**

- `if/else` clause written inside `changeCatStep()` is not correct.
- Syntax for style binding via `:class` is not correct.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categoryNameClass: null,
    step_1_active: false,
    step_2_active: false
  },
  mounted(){
    this.categoryNameClass = 'category-name';
  },
  methods: {
    changeCatStep(step) {
      if (step === 'step1') {
        this.step_1_active = true;
        this.step_2_active = false;
      } else {
        this.step_1_active = false;
        this.step_2_active = true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.cat-category-name-color {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <a href="#step-1"
       type="button"
       :class="step_1_active ? `cat-${categoryNameClass}-color` : null" class="btn btn-primary"
       @click="changeCatStep('step1')">Step 1</a>

    <a href="#step-2"
       type="button"
       :class="step_2_active ? `cat-${categoryNameClass}-color` : null" class="btn btn-primary"
       @click="changeCatStep('step2')">Step 2</a>
  </template>
</div>
```